# Fetching from an API returning either String or Double

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, struct

I am fetching from an API that depending on the objec I am fetching (here `price`) returns either a `string` or a `double`.

I previously added an `init` to my API decoding `struct` that allows to fetch both, by converting the `string` to a `double` if needed:

```
struct CryptoCURRENCY : Decodable {

    let price : Double
    let percentChange24h : Double

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case price = "PRICE"
        case percentChange24h = "CHANGEPCT24HOUR"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        percentChange24h = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .percentChange24h)
        do {
            price = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .price)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(_, _) {
            let stringValue = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .price)
            price = Double(stringValue)!
        }
    }
}
```

I had an issue with the API that required to change the fetching function and now the `init` is not taken into account anymore, any value returned as a `string` is ignored.

**How can I modify the following code to either take the `init` into account or do the same thing which is converting a `string` into a `double` if needed so it can be saved?**

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            completion(nil, error ?? FetchError.unknownNetworkError)
            return
        }
        do {
            if let outerJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                if let cryptoJSON : [String: Any] = outerJSON["RAW"] as? [String : Any] {
                    if let currencyJSON : [String: Any] = cryptoJSON[cryptoSym] as? [String : Any] {
                        if let actualJSON : [String: Any] = currencyJSON[currency] as? [String : Any] {
                            if let price = actualJSON["PRICE"] as? Double {
                                cryptoDoublePrice = price
                                CryptoInfo.cryptoPriceDic[cryptoPrice] = cryptoDoublePrice
                            }
                            if let percent = actualJSON["CHANGEPCT24HOUR"] as? Double {
                                cryptoDoublePercent = percent
                                CryptoInfo.cryptoPercentDic[cryptoPercent] = cryptoDoublePercent
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let parseError {
            completion(nil, parseError)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this was a really dumb question, I feel like asking questions here help me think correctly about the problems and find answers myself more easily tho, I might force myself to wait 10 minutes after writing a question before submiting it haha.

I simply did:

```
if let price = actualJSON["PRICE"] as? Double {
    cryptoDoublePrice = price
    CryptoInfo.cryptoPriceDic[cryptoPrice] = cryptoDoublePrice
}
if let price = actualJSON["PRICE"] as? String {
    cryptoDoublePrice = Double(price)!
    CryptoInfo.cryptoPriceDic[cryptoPrice] = cryptoDoublePrice
}
```

I might work on something better optimized tho.